# CSS File name works but file path doesn't

Tags: html, css, path, filepath

I have used the Sublime text editor to make a simple CSS file with an objective to make the heading red. Now the below code works perfectly fine

```
h1 {
color:red;
```

}

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="st.css" type="text/css">   
<title>Minutes</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>A</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

But if I replace the CSS file name from "st.css" to its original file path, it no longer works.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\windows\Desktop\Python\Practise\st.css" type="text/css">  
<title>Minutes</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>A</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any specific reason for this?
I tried refreshing, saving and even live reload but it simply doesn't work. Please explain

Comment: The code that works is using `relative` path and other uses `absolute` you can read more [here](http://www.scriptingok.com/tutorial/HTML-links-2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I figured it out myself.
I was sure that there couldn't be a typo since I right-clicked *(holding shift)* on my CSS file and copied its path. I think the problem was on **how my browser sees the text**.
For example, the below code which has a code path I copied as I mentioned works perfectly fine on **Internet Explorer**

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\Users\windows\Desktop\Python\Practise\st.css" type="text/css">  
<title>Minutes</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>A</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I saw the pathname on Internet Explorer's URL as

```
C:\Users\windows\Desktop\Python\Practise\Minutes.html
```

Now the same code didn't work for **Mozilla Firefox** which is my primary browser as I noticed the difference between the URL of Firefox and Explorer was of some random slashes at the start, like this

```
file:///C:/Users/windows/Desktop/Python/Practise/Minutes.html
```

Therefore I put the **file:///** text on my original code as

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///C:\Users\windows\Desktop\Python\Practise\st.css" type="text/css">  
<title>Minutes</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>A</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I even **interchanged** the backward and forward slashes and it still **worked !**

So I can conclude that my problem was a **browser-specific error** and I am really grateful to the community for their quick responses.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine to me. I would just double check that you have the full path correct with no typos or missing directories. I tried the same locally with the equivalent fully qualified path on my Windows machine and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit the backslashes of the path to normal slashes.

Another way to solve this problem is to have a look at this website because there is a nice example on it.

https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/

If you have any more questions feel free to ask.
I hope that I could help you!

Answer (score 0):

**If** you're using a *server/localhost*, You are not allowed to load local resources, that are NOT inside your main website folder, **for example**: if you have a folder named `mywebsite` which contains `mywebsite/index.html`, then once you click twice on index.html, You are allowed to access all files inside you computer, **BUT** if you run `mywebsite` in localhost **you'are only allowed** to access files inside `mywebsite` folder.

**If not** You probably made a typo in your absolute path, because your code is working fine in my device.